# Setting\Placing a DIV(CSS Layer) with table cell as reference

Tags: css, html

you may skip the following HTML code to proceed to actual question

```
<!-- Some HTML Code-->
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="1">
<tr>
    <td rowspan="03" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="60%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="03" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

the output of the above code will be somewhat like this 
[image]

now i want i CSS Layer (a DIV) setup with the center-cell (red bordered cell) as its **REFERENCE** how to do it...

```
 #myLayer{
 position: ? ;
 left    : ? ;
 right   : ? ;
 top     : ? ;
 bottom  : ? ;
 padding : ? ;
 width   : * ;
 height  : * ;
 z-index : 2 ;
 }
```

and where to place the **`<div id="*"></div>`** tag

Comment: Does the div have a variable or fixed height?

Comment: What do you mean by "as its reference" exactly? Do you want to position elements relative to that rectangle?

Comment: Are you talking about position: absolute?  If so, make yoru container div position:relative and everything inside of it will be placed relative to the containers top corner, instead of the page's.

Comment: What @Zoidberg says is effectively the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure if this is what you're trying to do, but you could give the red-bordered td an id and place the div inside of it. Then use the following CSS:

```
#mainTD {
    position: relative;
}

#myLayer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

I never use tables for layout so I don't know if this will react how I think it will, but this should make #myLayer's top, left, bottom, and right coordinates relative to the coordinates of its parent, #mainTD. So in the instance above, with top and left set to 0, #myLayer's top-left corner should be at #mainTD's top-left corner.